# How to test the result of cSpade

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm new working with sequences rules and I am little lost about what is the next step.
 I already generate the rules but I'm not sure how to test them in a new dataset, in order to verify them.

Do I have to execute again the cspade algorithm and expect that the new result seems similar to the first one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks